# Deploying Django using Phusion Passenger - file upload failure

Tags: apache-http-server, python, django, passenger

I have a Django app deployed using Passenger (I did not choose mod_wsgi because mod_passenger is already there and being used).  When I uploaded an MP3 file (900 kB), Google Chrome displays upload % which reached 100% pretty fast but then it took forever for the resulting page.  The database (containing the file's metadata) does not show anything uploaded.

The Django logic should be OK because everything works in the development machine (built-in Python server)

My config: Django 1.8, Apache 2.4, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs? That's where I would start. There should be messages from the Passenger module in there that would help shed light on the issue.

Comment: No log entries relating to the upload are found in the apache error log

Comment: Perhaps these are in Django logs? What's you Apache setup like? just stock the way that passenger tells you to set it up? Are you running modSecurity?

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided here by a Passenger Author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842187/django-file-upload-took-forever-with-phusion-passenger

Basically, upgrade to version 5 of Passenger.